# Which one is correct " I have done a lot of cooking lately" and "I have been doing a lot of cooking lately"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct " I have done a lot of cooking lately" and "I have been doing a lot of cooking lately" ? As far as I know, "Lately" is mostly used in the present perfect continuous, but when I choose "I have been doing a lot of cooking lately" as the correct answer, they said it is wrong. So, I am so confused about those two sentences.

Comment: They both convey the same meaning but there can be a subtle difference.......https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111386/lately-and-recently-in-present-perfect

Comment: When they said it was wrong, What was the context of the question? Because it had to be more than just “Which one is grammatically correct A or B?”   They are both grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: They're both fine.  Slightly different implications, but nothing significant in most contexts.

Comment: @Hot Licks Could you explain the slightly different implications?

Comment: @anouk - "Done" sort of implies that the cooking is over.  "Doing", not so much.